# How get the ID of select value from a dropdownlist and send it to a modal in php with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CoFa.png]

The Button:

echo CHtml::link('',array('modelo/ajaxnuevomodelo','id'=>$model->marcaID),array('class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary','data-placement'=>'top','data-target'=>'#extraModal', 'data-toggle'=>'modal','onclick'=>'AjaxExtra($(this).attr("href"))')); ?>

The ajax function

```
    $('#Vehiculo_marcaID').change(function(){
        //var vehiculomarca = jQuery('#Vehiculo_marcaID').val();
        var vehiculomarca = $('#Vehiculo_marcaID').val();
```

//I DONT' KNOW WHAT TO DO!!! 
        });

Comment: have you tried to send an ajax request?

Comment: I know a little bit of ajax, I'm a beginner with that, but yes, I haven't had good results. :/

Comment: Show your bad results as it is necessary to get a clue what you try to achieve

Comment: I've deleted all the code I've tried, I just got this:
  $('#Vehiculo_marcaID').change(function(){
        //var vehiculomarca = jQuery('#Vehiculo_marcaID').val();
        var vehiculomarca = $('#Vehiculo_marcaID').val();
});

The example of gbillig is good, get the id, now I need send this to the button of the modal.

Comment: Any update to this issue? Did my answer clearify the question(s) that you had? If yes, kindly consider accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking a bit of crucial information. Firstly, what is the HTML markup specifically? We don't have any notation of an id, class or similar to make the proper *selector* to fetch the value that you desire.

However, I am going to try and post an appropriate answer to the question(s) that you have in this regard, although I am going to use some pseudo notations due to this lack of information. The general gist should be applicable to the problem at hand.

So here goes.

From what we can interpret from your screenshot, you have a `<select>` element containing some options, which you would like to parse through an AJAX function. Seeing as you can have multiple selects (judging by the "+" button), the easiest way would be to use the `serialize()` function (note that this is a jQuery notation), to serialize your inputs into an array format. You will then need to loop through this array wherever you choose to handle your data parsed by the AJAX function.

In order to *serialize* your data, you'll need an element which contains your input data. My guess is that you already have a `<form>` element or similar (div element works as well) which contains your inputs.

This element containing your input elements needs to have an *id* or similar attribute so that we have something to target in terms of serializing the data.

example:

```
<div id="myForm">
    <select class="mySelect">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In the example given above, I have a *div* element containing my select (can be multiple selects, it doesn't matter). I gave my *div* element an id named *myForm*. I can now use this id in my selector to target that element and serialize the data inside it (in this case, the selects).

So in my case, my selector would look like this (in jQuery notation):

`$('#myForm').serialize();`.

Note that there are 2 methods of serializing the data, depending on what you want. The `.serialize();` is the standard url-encoded format of serialized data. Another option is `.serializeArray();` which gives you a JSON object. It all depends what kind of data format you wish to work with.

With this information we can now move on to the AJAX function itself. Note that again, I will be using jQuery notation. I really like the jQuery notation for AJAX functions specifically, because it's easy to read and understand. Also note that I will be using my own specified *pseudo notations* to keep continuity in what I am currently presenting throughout this answer.

Example of the AJAX function:

```
<script>
function submitData() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/your_page.php",
        data : {
            formData=$('#myForm').serialize()
        },
        success: function (html) {
            //do something on success
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Firstly in the AJAX function, we define how our data will be parsed in the `type:` option. Most common types are `POST` and `GET`. You can look up the differences between these two methods of parsing the data and determine which would be the better version for your solution. In your situation I would guess that the better choice would be to use *POST*.

Secondly we choose where the data will be sent (what page/url specifically). This is where the data will be sent and where you will handle the data to do whatever it is you wish to do with it.

Thirdly we specify the data that we are sending. This goes back to what I've already touched about *selectors* and *serializing* the data into an array which you can loop through to get the specified result(s).

Lastly I also included a *success* function if you wish to have some extra functionality on success. It could be a message to the user informing them that they have in fact sent the data for evaluation or whatever you wish to do. You can leave it out completely, but I personally think it's a nice functionality to have. You can do a lot of things with it.

Note that I have encapsulated the AJAX function itself within another function called `submitData()`. You can fire this by having an `onclick` attribute on the button that submits the data. You can also have an onclick *function* instead to handle the AJAX function, which would be the better example if I'm completely honest. `$('#myButton').on("click", function() { //do the AJAX function });`.

So that's basically how you can do it with AJAX. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Segue um exemplo funcional 
Translation
Here is a functional example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#Vehiculo_marcaID").change(function(){
        var marca = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        alert("Você selecionou a marca - " + marca);
    });
});
```

You can do so

```
$("#btnid").on('click', function(){
  let marca = $("select#Vehiculo_marcaID").children("option:selected").val();
  let modelo = $("select#Vehiculo_modeloID").children("option:selected").val();
  Here the rest of your logic to open the modal
});
```

Comment: Since the OP is asking in English it would only be appropriate to answer in English.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, it works, ....now I need send this marca to the modal through that link CHtml::link('',array('modelo/ajaxnuevomodelo','id'=>$model->marcaID),array('class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary','data-placement'=>'top','data-target'=>'#extraModal', 'data-toggle'=>'modal','onclick'=>'AjaxExtra($(this).attr("href"))')); ?> :D

Comment: @Bernhard Plis explain

Comment: What modal are you using?